# Adding field values within Query

Tags: ms-access

I have the following Query:

[image]

I want the **QTotal** to show the total of the Q1 to Q4 fields but it comes up blank.

I have tried:

```
 Qtotal: Nz([Q1])+Nz([Q2])+Nz([Q3])+Nz([Q4])
```

but this throws and exepction the first time the query is run and then it works.

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Obviously, that's a VBA error, not an SQL one. Share the relevant VBA. How are you calling this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-write that query using IIf(IsNull... instead of Nz(... Pretty sure there are some incompatibility issues with the Nz function.

Comment: Perfect. Changed to Qtotal: IIf(IsNull([Q1]),0,[Q1])+IIf(IsNull([Q2]),0,[Q2])+IIf(IsNull([Q3]),0,[Q3])+IIf(IsNull([Q4]),0,[Q4]) and all good. I guess that is what you meant Thanks